# jQuery dynamic form submit twice

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have tried to create form dynamically and submit it on server, where data is list of `$(<checkbox>)`.

```
$('<form>').attr("method", "post")
           .attr('action', '/proceed')
           .append(data)
           .submit();
```

The problem that on server comes 2 requests: post with data  and get without data  -just empty form.

Submit happens once, I have tried to unbind submit before.

Comment: Are you calling your code in an existing `submit` handler, or on the `click` of a `submit` action? If so, you'll need to cancel that submit before you do yours (`return false;` from the event handler).

Comment: I have a <button> element and click handler for it

$('.activateEventButton').on('click', function (e) {
            activateEvents();
        });

Answer (score 0):

The default action of a `<button />` is to submit the form when it's clicked.

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to cancel this submission before you create your own;

```
 $('.activateEventButton').on('click', function (e) { 
     activateEvents(); 

     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the submission.
 });
```

Comment: Thats for this point, but it does not works.
And what is strange, the second submit comes by GET, but the first one by POST

The GET request comes empty, without any data, POST is normal with data

Comment: @ekitru: Are you sure the the `GET` is a second submission rather than a redirect after the POST is received? Does the POST contain the correct form information? Have you got *any* other code using this form? (and any plugins?)

Comment: No, I have not, but in browser I see that after first  POST page is redirected right, and after that comed GET request to server  without data.

But I am not sure, why after submit() page is redirected separetly

Comment: That would indicate to me that the `POST` is returning a redirect header (and therefore a `301`, or `302` status). You should be able to check the response headers of the POST request with your dev tools to confirm this. In Chrome at least, click the "preserve log upon navigation" to make this possible... redirecting after POSTing is a best-practice for preventing duplicate form submissions.

Comment: on POST  returns 200 <- as I understand meands validation ok and go ahead
on GET   returns 302 <- this is strtange call, who redirect ?